# Not using index even if it exists

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing

I have next simple query: `SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table.id WHERE table.id=1` having an index in table.id and table2.id

When I check how it works with `EXPLAIN` it shows that it's not using the index, and going through ALL the rows. I check the same with another another exact table with the same structure, and in this case index is being used.

Even more strange, if I have another more complex query like 
`SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table.id LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.id=table.id WHERE table.id=1` the index works perfect in both tables, even in the problematic `table2`

I'm completely sure that is my mistake, but I really don't know why sometimes index is being used, and sometimes not... Anyone expert in MySQL who can help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: How big is the table (both in terms of rows and columns).   Sometimes a query analyzer will decide a full table scan is more efficient for small tables...

Comment: I'm still in development, so the "table2" has 10 rows. But anyway, sometimes the index is being used and sometimes not, that's the problem..!

Comment: Why is that a problem?   I wouldn't try to second guess the optimizer, it seems like you've got the proper indexes available, see if the problem still occurs with more data...

Comment: I will check it, but I thought it was a problem (I'm obsessed with optimize everything), or maybe some detail that I don't know about how indexes work. Thank you ;)

Comment: If you would have more rows the index will probably be used the engine of the db decided that is more economical to use full table scan.Use optimization when you need it,premature optimization will send you chasing shadows.